# Is it possible reuse function argument as an object?

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to do this?

```
function getVariable(elem) {
    return $scope.elem;
}
```

or this;

```
function getField(field) {
   return data[0].field;
}
```

`getField('price')` should return the equivalent of `data[0].price` and

`getVariable('id')` should return the value of `$scope.id`

Upon experimenting, I've found that for example `getField('price')` is looking for `data[0].field` as is in the function - not for `data[0].price`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the dot notation for object property access in Javascript, it evaluates the name literally. As you discovered, it's always looking for a property named "field" or "elem".

When you want is bracket syntax, i.e.:

```
function getField(fieldName) {
  return data[0][fieldName];
}
```

Same for your other function.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this, but never got rid of the dot - now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
(function(){
    var data = {
            'id' : 123,
            'name' : 'Toyata Camarry 2009',
            'price' : 14500
    },
    fxArgObject = function(field) {
        return data[field];
    };

    var price = fxArgObject('price');
    console.log(price);
})();
```